# How to add a css style to an element in the HTMLEditorField content editor in Silverstripe 4?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In SS 3.x we could use the following code to add custom elements into the `HTMLEditorField` content editor via the `Styles` dropdown. My main use for this was to turn a standard link into a styled button link.

How can we achieve this in SS 4.x?

***This is how it was done in 3.x***

`_config.php`

```
<?php
$formats = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Buttons'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Custom Button',
        'attributes' => array('class'=>'custom-btn'),
        'selector' => 'a'
    )
);
//Set the dropdown menu options
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('style_formats',$formats);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is create an `editor.css` file, put your styles in it and then put the following snippet in your `mysite/_config.php` file.

```
use SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\TinyMCEConfig;

TinyMCEConfig::get('cms')
    ->addButtonsToLine(1, 'styleselect')
    ->setOption('importcss_append', true);
```

The styles are automatically added to the drop down.

Reference: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/typography/#custom-style-dropdown